Wrong percentages with tbl_summary
I have two questions about the tbl_summary function from gtsummary package:
1)I need to perfom some calculations with tbl_summary. But i can`t make the percentages of the fim_mot variable to be referred to the total of the cohort.
tb_iris <- iris %>% 
  select(Species,Sepal.Length) %>%
   mutate(sepal_c = ifelse(Sepal.Length > 5, 
                           "Big", ifelse(Sepal.Length<5 & Sepal.Length>=4, "Medium", "Short")),
          sepal_c=replace(sepal_c, sepal_c=="Medium", NA)) %>%
  tbl_summary(by = Species,
              missing = "no",
              statistic = sepal_c ~ c("{n}/{N_obs} {p}"))


I want the result showed to be 22/50= 44% and not 73.33%. Any advices?

My second question is, why are showed a double % in my results? (SOLVED)


Please make your question reproducible. W.r.t. Q2 have you tried removing % from statistic-argument of tbl_summary?

Try ({p}%) instead of {p}%.

Just use the percent="cell" argument

gtsummary package calculates percentages out of the values displayed in the table for that category. If you have missing values, they are omitted from the percentage calculation. As a result, you get 73% instead of 44%.
One way to overcome this is to change the "Medium" category to "Unknown" (instead of NA) values:
library(tidyverse)
library(gtsummary)

tbl <- iris |> 
  select(Species,Sepal.Length) %>%
  mutate(sepal_c = ifelse(Sepal.Length > 5, 
                          "Big", ifelse(Sepal.Length<5 & Sepal.Length>=4, "Medium", "Short")),
         sepal_c=replace(sepal_c, sepal_c=="Medium", "Unknown")) 

tbl |>
  tbl_summary(by = Species,
              missing = "ifany",
              statistic = sepal_c ~ c("{n}/{N_obs} {p}%"), percent="column")

In this case, the output table will look like this:

There is also a table1 package, that can produce a similar table but allows you to remove missing value row:
library(table1)
table1(~ sepal_c + Sepal.Length | Species, data = tbl, overall=FALSE, render.missing = NULL)


